# How can I randomly set tags to my buttons and how can I know if they are the same at some point?

Tags: android, random, tags

Since I want to set the tags randomly, I would like to know when all the tags are either true or false. At one point I commented the if statement so I think the check method is working.

To check if the tags are the same i have something like this on my code (doesn't work though):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (button1.getTag().equals(true)){

                cambiarColorDos.grupoNueve();
                button1.setTag(false);
            }
            else if (button1.getTag().equals(false)){

                cambiarColorDos.grupoNueveMy();
                button1.setTag(true);


            }

            check();

         }              
    });
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (button2.getTag().equals(true)){

                cambiarColorDos.grupoNueve();
                button2.setTag(false);
            }
            else if (button2.getTag().equals(false)){

                cambiarColorDos.grupoNueveMy();
                button2.setTag(true);


            }

            check();

         }              
    });





protected void check() {


if (button1.getTag().equals(true) && button2.getTag().equal(true)

&& button3.getTag().equal(true)){


//Do Something


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use the same listener for all buttons. Replace all direct button access to using the View that's supplied to the listener, like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag().equals(true)){

            cambiarColorDos.grupoNueve();
            v.setTag(false);
        }
        else if (v.getTag().equals(false)){

            cambiarColorDos.grupoNueveMy();
            v.setTag(true);


        }

        check();

     }              
});
```

and attach it to all relevant buttons.

Second, you are not setting a ***default state (tag)*** to your buttons, and your code only checks for true and false, but leaves out the case where the buttons were never pressed and no tag was ever set. That probably means your listeners never change state.

Third, do you want `check()` to succeed if and only all tags are equal to ***true***? If that's the case your code is fine, if a bit messy. Here' my suggestion that avoids redundant `if`s:

```
protected void check() {
    if (!(button1.getTag().equals(true))
        return;

    ..... and so on for all buttons .....

    //Do Something

}
```

As for the random boolean part, you can use this:

```
public static boolean getRandomBool() {
   return Math.random() > 0.5;
}
```

It will return true about half of the times.

Comment: I set my default state tags manually just to test it so it will begin with an initial state but I want it to generate the tag randomly and i dont know how. Even so, when I set the condition to check if all tags are true or all false  the check method doesnt execute.

Comment: There are two issues. Are you getting these buttons from the view? Are you adding them programmatically? And when you say randomly do you mean you want each button to be assigned with a different starting tag?

Comment: Yes these buttons are from a view and I added them programmatically. When I say randomly I mean everytime I start my program I want it to randomly set a true or false tag for each of my buttons.

Comment: Updated my answer to incorporate that.